# Efficient algorithm for mesh scale adjustment based on the scale of another mesh

Tags: transformations

I have a mesh (Mesh-A) with a bounding box of some arbitrary size defined by X,Y,Z scale.
In runtime I import another mesh (Mesh-B),which has an overall topology similar to the Mesh-A, but it can have a different default scale. I am looking for an efficient algorithm to rescale the Mesh-B to have the new scale equal to the Mesh-A,which basically means - their bounding boxes are of similar sizes. The naive approach would be to run for... loop, scaling the Mesh-B transform,till its BB has an approximate size equal to that of  the Mesh-B's BB. I would like to learn other approaches.

Comment: Scaling by BB does not seem a very fruitful way to do anything. I mean a elephant does not have the same BB as a human. Ideally youd have some feature you can relate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scaling is linear, so you can do this in one step rather than iteratively. If you have two vector values `sizeA` and `sizeB` for the sizes of the two meshes’ bounding boxes, the vector value you should scale mesh B by is `sizeA / sizeB`. If you want to scale it uniformly, you’ll need to pick a single scalar value; one way to do that would be to average the ratios of each component, i.e. `(sizeA.x / sizeB.x + sizeA.y / sizeB.y + sizeA.z / sizeB.z) / 3`.